# Android - Compress Bitmap with applied PorterDuffColorFilter

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have a `Bitmap` with a `PorterDuffColorFilter` applied on it. But when I'm compressing this `Bitmap` to the file, the `PorterDuffColorFilter` disappears. How I can compress my `Bitmap` and don't lose `PorterDuffColorFilter`?

Here's some code which I'm using now:

---

```
public void PrepareFiles(Bitmap original_img)
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap b = convert(original_img, 0xFFFF0000);

        String path1 = "/sdcard/red.png";

        File f1 = new File(path1);
        if (!f1.exists()) {
            f1.createNewFile();
        }
        else
        {
            f1.delete();
            f1.createNewFile();
        }

        FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream(path1);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos1);
        b.recycle();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public Bitmap convert(Bitmap src, int color)
{
    BitmapDrawable temp = new BitmapDrawable(src);
    temp.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.ADD));
    return temp.getBitmap();
}
```

Comment: Really a Good Question!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot set a `ColorFilter` on a `Bitmap`. In your code you are setting the `ColorFilter` on a `BitmapDrawable`. Doing so doesn't change the underlying `Bitmap` instance. To solve your problem you will have to create a new `Bitmap`, attach a `Canvas` to it and draw the original bitmap on the canvas using a `Paint` which has the required `ColorFilter`. Here's an example:

```
// The original bitmap
Bitmap src = ...;
// an empty bitmap with the same dimensions as the original one
Bitmap filteredBitmap = Bitmap.create(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(filteredBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint(); // no need to set Paint.FILTER_BITMAP flag
paint.setColorFilter(colorFilter); // set the required color filter
canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0f, 0f, paint);
```

After this save the 'filteredBitmap' to a file.

Comment: I think you can draw the original bitmap on itself. But I am not sure.

Comment: And how I can save it to a file?

Comment: As you are doing now. The 'saving to a file' part of your solution isn't wrong.